# AWS EventBridge - How to see if a rule has been deleted and by who

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

In AWS EventBridge how can I see if a rule has been deleted and who deleted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to see that from EventBridge. You would need to have a look at the CloudTrail logs for the `DeleteRule` action.